# BDD tool for Scala supporting reusable parameterized Gherkin clauses

Tags: java, scala, bdd, specs, scalatest

Is there any BDD tool for Scala supporting reusable parameterized Gherkin clauses?

I would like to be able to have the ability to use specs like these:

```
Given number 4 is entered
When "+" is pressed
And number -1 is entered
And "*" is pressed
And number 2 is entered
And "=" is pressed
Then result is 6
```

And I would like to define fixtures to Gherkin clauses differing by a parameter only once, something like:

```
scenario("(4+(-1)) * 2 = 6") {

  given("number 4 is entered")
  when("'+' is pressed")
  and("number -1 is entered")
  and("'*' is pressed")
  and("number 2 is entered")
  and("'=' is pressed")
  then("result is 0")
}
```

Given definitions of clauses looking like as follows:

```
"number $number is entered" {
    calculator.enter(number)
}
"'$key' is pressed" {
    calculator.press(key)
}
"result is $number" {
    assert(calculator.getDisplayedNumber === number)
}
```

I looked through ScalaTest and Specs manuals but I didn't find such feature. ScalaTest seems to be able to reuse the defined clause in a different scenario, but looks like it is not parameterised.

Do you know some tools that does support what I want, or e.g. some extensions to ScalaTest, or a way to extend it myself with such result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can find the following example in specs2 to implement Given When Then specs :
https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/1.6/src/test/scala/org/specs2/examples/GivenWhenThenSpec.scala

Hope this will help.